# Grab the contents of a Drupal website that is secured with a login form

Tags: c#, drupal, httpwebrequest, screen-scraping

I would like to grab some content from a website that is made with Drupal. 
The challenge here is that i need to login on this site before i can access the page i want to scrape. Is there a way to automate this login process in my C# code, so i can grab the secure content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the secured content, you'll need to store and send *cookies* with every request to your server, starting with the request that sends your log in info and then saving the session cookie that the server gives you (which is your proof that you are who you say you are).

You can use the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` for a less control but out-of-the-box solution that will handle cookies.

My preferred method is to use `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` to send and receive all web data and then use the **HtmlAgilityPack** to parse the returned data into a *Document Object Model* (DOM) which can be easily read from.

The trick to getting `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` to work is that you must create a long-lived `System.Net.CookieContainer` that will keep track of your log in info (and other things the server expects you to keep track of). The good news is that the `HttpWebRequest` will take care of all of this for you if you provide the container.

You need a new `HttpWebRequest` for each call you make, so you must sets their `.CookieContainer` to the same object every time. Here is an example:

### UNTESTED

```
using System.Net;

public void TestConnect()
{
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.mysite.com/login.htm");
    request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    // do page parsing and request setting here
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.mysite.com/submit_login.htm");
    // add specific page parameters here
    request.CookeContainer = cookieJar;
    response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.mysite.com/secured_page.htm");
    request.CookeContainer = cookieJar;
    // this will now work since you have saved your authentication cookies in 'cookieJar'
    response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

[HttpWebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx

Comment: I already tried the HttpWebRequest. But didn't get very far with it and that made me think, maybe there is something Drupal specific..  But i'll give it another go.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module to do that. Also check out [this](http://drupal.org/node/394364) link for a bit of explanation.

Comment: I agree with @pguardiario that this has almost nothing to do with what the server is running. Suggesting that they modify the server so that they can scrape data from a secured portion of it isn't an answer that many people will get traction with.